# Passing json array through url not working in IE

Tags: php, url, joomla, joomla2.5, json

I have a problem while try to send compressed array through url in php. Here what i have tried so far. I have a array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 191
    [1] => 192
    [2] => 193
    [3] => 194
)
```

then I compressed it using `json_encode` like below:

```
$compress_data = json_encode($cid);
```

and try to pass that data through url like below:

```
<a href='index.php?option=com_audits&controller=audits&task=createcsv&create=success&cid=<?php echo $compress_data?>&tmpl=component' target="_blank">
                    <img src="<?php echo JURI::root().'images/csv_button.png'?>" width="18" border="0" height="18">
</a>
```

It all works fine for rest of the browsers but not in IE. when I checked it then i realize it get breaks in between when first double quote occurred in json data. I don't know why is it happing as this works for all other. Is there any way to solve it.Please help.

Comment: You might like check out this [link if it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588413/json-structure-not-working-in-ie7-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `urlencode($compress_data)` instead of `$compress_data` because url string must respond to RFC: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html